# Google vault Export API not working with Cloud storage API

Tags: google-vault-api

Google vault provide an option to export the search via API as per the documentation.

Reg.: https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/08/google-vault-export-api.html

But the Cloud storage API is not pulling the export. I am getting below error.

{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "xx@xx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to xxxx-abc8-461e-b3f0-8551852ec7e1/d9d0ee98-9851-494e-a5d9-43a3749a0e4a/exportly-45be9489-633e-43c1-a2a9-68e7d4caff55/Export-Sam-1541598626393-1.zip.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "xxx@xx.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to xxxx-461e-b3f0-8551852ec7e1/d9d0ee98-9851-494e-a5d9-43a3749a0e4a/exportly-45be9489-633e-43c1-a2a9-68e7d4caff55/Export-Sam-1541598626393-1.zip."
}

I have the Service account with Owner role. Still, I am getting the same error. I have created the Export with the same Service account.